# In Visual Studio 2010, how do I copy directory structure to test output?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have a project that has a directory called "Data" containing various data files, like XML and XSD files.  I have these files specified as "Content" and "Copy Always" and they copy just fine to /bin/ on build with the directory structure intact (ie., /bin/Data/).

I've also added these directories to the .testsettings Deployment list.  I've tried to do this both by setting the individual files to deploy, and as setting the directory.  In both cases, it just copies the files themselves into the output directory, but does not preserve the directory structure.

How do I tell Visual Studio to preserve the directory structure when copying files to the test output directory?  I would prefer not to have to use post-build events.  It just seems crazy to me that the test setup is different than the build setup.

Thanks.

Luke

Comment: Since this question is already some months old... did you manage to find a solution?